# Iterate through selected items in an unsorted list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently developing a remote file browser that allows the user to multi-select files and to delete the selected files together. The list is essentially a styled unordered list:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a>File one</a></li>
  <li><a>File two</a></li>
  <li><a>File three</a></li>
  <li><a>File four</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've added a jQuery script that changes adds a style class to an li (i.e. highlights the item) when it is clicked:

```
var lis = $('.nav li a').click(function(e){
    if(!e.ctrlKey) {
         lis.removeClass("selected");      
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");    
});
```

Now I want to implement a delete function that has to decide which files are selected, but I am unsure what is the best way to do this.

The easiest way will be to loop through the li entries and to check which entries are styled the class "selected".

Is this method advisable? That is, it is a good idea to use classes as flags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use class selector to build required selector. there is no need to iterate over all li element and check for class selected existance:

```
$('.selected');
```

to remove li having anchor as selected:

```
$('.selected').parent().remove()
```

or

```
$('li:has(.selected)').remove()
```

Comment: When the delete button is clicked, I would need to gather the names of all files that are selected and to delete all the selected files together. How may this solution be used? It seems to only be able to delete a file at a time.

Comment: @YiyuanLee: do you mean li elements?? in that case you need to traverse to li and delete them: `$('.selected').parent().remove()`

Comment: Yup. Does this delete all li's in the ul that is 'selected', or just the first one?

Comment: it will delete all of them.